# Bash rename files from "test.file.1" to "test file 1"

Tags: bash

I have a folder with a bunch of files that contain . and i would like to rename all the folders or files to replace the . with space through out the file names

I've tried to use the rename tool but its spits out problems

```
rename -v ’s/\./\ /’ *

Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after {
#line 1 <-- HERE near column 15 at (user-supplied code).
```

when `rename '.' ' '` i get

```
syntax error at (user-supplied code), near "."
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Files with spaces in their names are more difficult to manage.

Comment: Its for ease of reading on a Windows shared folder

Comment: Ok. Would `-` or `_` be an option? (If you need spaces, you need spaces.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiith find you can do:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec bash -c 'n="${0##*/}"; mv "$0" "${0%/*}/${n//./ }"' {} \;
```

If you wanna use tools specifically for file renaming, then

With `rename`:

```
rename 's/\./ /g' *
```

I have my own tool that I use for file/folder renaming: [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm)

```
rnm -rs '/\./ /g' *
```

Comment: @MichaelBurns : I rewrote the find command and also added other methods including my own file renaming tool.